# Load a tree-like structure in Ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have an entity `Node` that references itself in order to create a tree-like structure.

Here is the migration:

```
create table(:nodes) do
  add :name, :string, null: false, size: 64
  add :parent_id, references(:nodes, on_delete: :nothing)
end
```

And here the schema definition:

```
schema "nodes" do
  field :name, :string
  belongs_to :parent, Node
  has_many :children, Node, foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

I am trying to load the entire tree using this approach:

```
root_nodes = Repo.all(
  from n in Node,
    where:  is_nil(n.parent_id) # Root nodes don't have a parent
)

nodes = Enum.map(root_nodes, fn(n) ->
  Ecto.build_assoc(n, :children, load_children(n.id))
end)
```

Where:

```
defp load_children(parent_id) do
  nodes = Repo.all(
    from n in Node,
      where: n.parent_id == ^parent_id
  )
  if nodes != [] do
    # If children aren't empty, apply recursively
    nodes = Enum.map(nodes, fn(n) ->
      Ecto.build_assoc(n, :children, load_children(n.id))
    end)
  end

  nodes
end
```

but I get:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.drop_meta/1
```

Generally, I think I struggle with understanding of how Ecto ORM should be used. Most of the tutorials show only examples of how to fetch isolated rows, or with one level of preloading. How should I load a tree-like structure? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Asa far as I can see, build_assoc is used incorrectly. Why don't you simply set the value to :children, the results of queries contain all the values including parent_id.
When it comes to the problem you're actually facing, Michal has the answer below - use recursive queries if you're using posgresql. If you read a lot often and rarely add a new row in this table, use nested sets.

Comment: Ecto supports recursive CTE. see https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#with_cte/3 .
If you want to understand recursive queries better, check this out: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-recursive-query/

Answer (score 9):

Ecto is not a regular ORM in that where most ORMs try to abstract the database completely, ecto tends to be close to the underlying database semantics.

This means that the real question is not "How do I load a tree-like structure with Ecto". But "How do I load a tree-like structure with SQL" (assuming that's what you use).

Unsurprisingly, the answer is that it's very complex - either requires one query for each nesting level (horribly inefficient), [recursive queries](https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres) or changing the representation (storing the full path and not just parent_id, or with the [Nested Set model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)).

If you keep the `parent_id`-only approach, the simplest way, might be to load everything upfront and stitch appropriately after loading in the correct place (the advantage is that you perform only one query).

While this does not answer the question directly (since there's not a good answer), I hope this does give you ideas where to look for solutions and how you could change the approach to make it easier.